# 'If he did respect' is possible in the second conditional

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

> He is not a popular teacher. He does not respect students. He  would be
>   a popular teacher if he respected students.

One of my students wrote:

> If he did respect students he would be~.

Have you seen this? I haven't. What do you think?

Comment: *Did* is somewhat of an intensifier here, to emphasize that he actually doesn't respect his students.

Comment: I believe that the second sentence in the top block should be "He does not respect students."

Comment: You are right. It's a typo. It's 'He doesnot respect'.

Comment: Scott, do u think it is possible to say 'if he did respect~'?

Comment: "Respected" and "did respect" are pretty much interchangeable, in the context above.